# Group list by rules in sequence using DateDifference and Total

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering, subset

I have a list and would like to group it into sublists using a couple rules.

First rule: the date difference between sequential elements is less than 3.
Second Rule: the total of the second elements can't be greater than 10.

```
list={{{2003, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 7}, {{2003, 8, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 3}, {{2003, 8, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 8, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}, {{2003, 8, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}, {{2003, 8, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 4}, {{2003, 8, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 3}, {{2003, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 8, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}, {{2003, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 7}, {{2003, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}, {{2003, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}, {{2003, 9, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}, {{2003, 9, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}, {{2003, 9, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 5}, {{2003, 9, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 4}, {{2003, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}}

correctAnswer = {
  {{{2003, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 7}, {{2003, 8, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 3}},
  {{{2003, 8, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 8, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}},
  {{{2003, 8, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}, {{2003, 8, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 4}, {{2003, 8, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 3}},
  {{{2003, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 8, 31, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}},
  {{{2003, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 7}, {{2003, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}, {{2003, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}},
  {{{2003, 9, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 9, 21, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}},
  {{{2003, 9, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 1}, {{2003, 9, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 5}, {{2003, 9, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 4}},
  {{{2003, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 8}, {{2003, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 2}}
  }

dayDiff[date1_, date2_] := QuantityMagnitude[DateDifference[date1, date2,"Day"]]
```

I have tried

```
GatherBy[list, dayDiff[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]]<=2  && Total[#[[2]] <= 10] &]
```

to no avail.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
split[list_] := Module[{sum = list[[1, 2]]},
    Split[list,
       If[dayDiff[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]] <= 2 && (sum = sum + #2[[2]]) <= 10,
          True,
          sum = #2[[2]];
          False
       ] &
    ]
];
```

This gives the correct answer:

```
split[list] == correctAnswer
(* True *)
```

**Update**

A rewriting of `split` to avoid the `If` statement:

```
split2[list_] := Module[{sum = list[[1, 2]]}, 
    Split[list,
       (dayDiff[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]] <= 2 && (sum = sum + #2[[2]]) <= 10) ||
       (sum = #2[[2]]; False) &
    ]
];
```

This yields the same result:

```
split[list] == split2[list]
(* True *)
```

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  I'm not immediately clear on how it works but will figure it out.  Thank you again.

Comment: @RayTroy Glad this is helpful and thanks for the accept. `Split` processes its elements two-by-two, so I'm using a local variable to keep track of the sum of all the elements that will form a sublist. At each step of the reading made by `Split`, a new element enters the play (namely `#2`). The code takes the value of its second element and add it to the sum (provided `dayDiff` was satisfied). If the result is smaller than or equal to the bound, this element will join the sublist that is being created by `Split`, otherwise the sublist will be created and a new one will start with this element.

Comment: @RayTroy In this case, the value of the sum is set to the second element of this element (namely, `#2[[2]]`), and the reading of `Split` continues with the following element in the list.